# Detect current VSIX package's version from code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix, vspackage

I am writing a VSIX project and I would like for the code to be able to determine whether an update is available.

I know Visual Studio would be able to check for the update, however, I would like for the extension to be able to prompt user (developer) more verbosely.

1. I wonder how could make the extension read its own version from the package manifest?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just pull the version information from the immediate assembly?

Comment: @Lloyd, thanks for the reply. The immediate assembly's version info is not synch with vsix's version info. To keep that in sync might be a good idea too. Thanks.

Comment: [Productivity Power Tools for Visual Studio 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) provide status tray notifications of extension updates. This became a [standard feature starting in Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/04/06/improving-how-we-update-visual-studio.aspx). **Do not reimplement this feature in a non-standard manner**; rather, inform your users about the existing feature.

Comment: @280Z28, thanks for the feedback and advice. As stated above, I am fully aware about the standard Visual Studio notification. Regardless of that (to reimplement that or not), my question still stands.

Comment: Now how can we get the current extension version on _Visual Studio Gallery_ to compare with the local version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found that I could read the version information directly from the manifest XML file.

```
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(manifestPath);
        var metaData = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlElement>().First(x => x.Name == "Metadata");
        var identity = metaData.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlElement>().First(x => x.Name == "Identity");
        var version = identity.GetAttribute("Version");
```

I also wrote a [gist C# class code](https://gist.github.com/nordinrahman/11037855#file-vsixmanifest-cs) that encapsulate the code above. Besides, version, this technique could be used to get other information provided by the manifest file.

Comment: Thanks man, just was trying to find solution to that question too. You saved a lot of time for me

Comment: @AliSharabiani You may want to review the gist I provide in the answer above. It should be (at least on my case) something like this: Path.Combine(assemblyDirectory, "extension.vsixmanifest")

Comment: @Nordin I tried that, it is same as using this code: `manifestPath = "extension.vsixmanifest"` (paths are relative in vspackage, that's why this also works). It works locally, however, when deploying the package on _Visual Studio Gallery_ and installing it; the path is wrong `Could not find file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\extension.vsixmanifest`.

Answer (score 7):

Nordin's solution seems good, but I just want to mention that there is one more way to get current version of the extension. I have no idea in what situation my solution might be better, maybe if you don't know the path to the manifest on the client that uses this extension.

```
// get ExtensionManager
IVsExtensionManager manager = GetService(typeof(SVsExtensionManager)) as IVsExtensionManager;
// get your extension by Product Id
IInstalledExtension myExtension = manager.GetInstalledExtension("ProductId-1234-1234-1234-123456789012");
// get current version
Version currentVersion = myExtension.Header.Version;
```

I call this inside `Initialize()` method of my package.

Comment: One thing missing, the dll for this isn't visible as a reference to add, you need to add it via browse from the following location - 

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager\{your version you want to use}\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.dll

Comment: Works like a champ! thanks! Tested on both _Visual Studio Experimental Instance_ and also after deploying the package.

Comment: This solution doesn't involve file system calls, which is better in some cases. You just take the value from the memory.

Comment: Am I missing something. What is GetService on the first line? Can you shared that code?

Answer (score 1):

This code motivated by Wayne Koorts works for me, even if deploying the package on Visual Studio Gallery:

```
    private string getVsixVersion()
    {
        var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var asmDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(asm.Location);
        var manifestPath = Path.Combine(asmDir, "extension.vsixmanifest");
        var version = "?";
        if (File.Exists(manifestPath))
        {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(manifestPath);
            var metaData = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlElement>().First(x => x.Name == "Metadata");
            var identity = metaData.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlElement>().First(x => x.Name == "Identity");
            version = identity.GetAttribute("Version");

        }
        return version;
    }
```