# How ot get Visual studio extension version from the extension code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, envdte, vs-extensibility

I would like to display the visual studio extension version in a UI, so that when a user has an issue and makes a screenshot the version will be "automatically" available.
Is there any interface to query for it?
I don't know if it matters, but it is better if I find examples in C#

Comment: Most likely, this will depend on which extension you are using. Can you be more specific?

Comment: It is its own version. My extension to be able to get its own version (the one from the manifest) which is also visible when you use Extensions->Manage Extensions and you point to a particular extension. On the right side of the dialog, Visual Studio displays the extension version. The same version is used when there is a new version, Visual Studio offers an update.
So I want to make it auto display its own version in a UI element that it has on its toolbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666144/detect-current-vsix-packages-version-from-code) shows how the extension version could be read from the manifest file through the extension code and also offers an alternative which is loading the manifest using the extension's GUID.

A third option would be to get the version of the executing assembly that is part of the extension, but this will only work if the version in the manifest file matches the version of the assemblies within the extension.